# Can't Connect to QuickBooks from apps.com Try/Buy

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Problem: From apps.com Try/Buy, I can't persist the connection to QuickBooks

I have the following scenerio:

Using: IPP .NET Web Forms Sample App V3   (IppDotNetSdkQuickBooksApiV3SampleWebFormsApp)

```
                    I am only changing Web.config with my application settings
```

Set OpenId URL: myapp.com/OpenID/connect.aspx

The user Signs-in with Intuit, Selects a company, Authorizes connection, lands on my site.

The user is Signed in, but the connection Status is: Not Connected.

If I use the C2QB button from myapp.com/ManageConnection, it will connect.

Are there changes that need to be made to the sample app to make it work for Try/Buy?

Or do I need a different OpenID URL?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to implement direcConnectToIntuit().
Please check this out:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/javascript_functions

EDIT:
So, I replicated your use case.
The issue is that in the sample app, if the user is a new user, then only the following line returns null in username and the code inside the loop gets executed for DirectConnectScript on Connect.aspx page.
   string userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(openIdEmail);

This is an expected behavior for Try/Buy because any 'new user' should only be redirected for Try/Buy. In other cases(for an existing user) you should be saving the realm and other details in DB and fetch those values from permanent store.

So, to make your testing easier, you can add the following deleteuser code below the following line on Connect.aspx page :
string userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(openIdEmail);
                    Membership.DeleteUser(userName);

This should help you in replicating the Try/Buy flow.

Comment: The DirectConnectToIntuit() is in the Connect.aspx in the sample app.  Why would it not call it?  Again, I have not changed the sample app except the web.config file.

Comment: Edited my answer above.